# How to calculate the number of different permutations and combinations of $n$ numbers while $q$ of them are the same?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The problem can be described as below:

*Give $n$ numbers while $q$ of them are the same, the rest are different from each other. Choose $m$ numbers,find out the amount of different permutations and combinations of the chosen $m$ numbers.*

For example, for $\{a_1, a_2, a_3,1,2\}$ while $a_1=a_2=a_3=k≠1,2$, if you calculate $P_5^5$, you will get the result 120. But in fact, for $$\begin{array}{c}
\left\{1,2, a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}\right\} \quad\left\{1,2, a_{1}, a_{3}, a_{2}\right\} \quad \left\{1,2, a_{2}, a_{1}, a_{3}\right\}  \\ \left\{1,2, a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{1}\right\} \quad \left\{1,2,
a_{3}, a_{1}, a_{2}\right\} \quad\left\{1,2, a_{3}, a_{2}, a_{1}\right\}
\end{array}$$, they are actually the same situation, $\{1,2,k,k,k\}$.Get rid of these results, the correct answer is $20=\frac{P^5_5}{P^1_3}$.

But when it comes to choose $m$ from $n$, things will be far more complex. Follow the example above, choose 4 numbers from $\{a_1, a_2, a_3,1,2\}$, if $a_1, a_2, a_3$ all appear, the result needs to be divided by 6; if two $a_i$s appear,the result needs to be divided by 2.

So what's the total number?  And what about the case of combinations? I hope to get the exact expression.

Answer (score 1):

Think of choosing $\alpha$ numbers from those q numbers, and then $m-\alpha$ from the rest $n-q$. Hence, the answer will be:

$\sum_{\alpha=max(0,m-n+q)}^{min(q,m)}$ $ {q}\choose{\alpha} $ $ {n-q}\choose{m-\alpha} $/ $\alpha!$